# AndroidStudio gradle build locked in :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac using Room

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 beta 6 / gradle: 3.0.0-beta6, and today I'm having problems with the compilation.

When I start the build (CTRL+F9), the process stop in operation: `":app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac"`
I wait more than 1 hour, and nothing change.

Gradle sync is ok, the problem is just the compilation.

I think it's a problem in my project, because I can compile another project without problem with this Android Studio version.

I did a lot of changes to this probject and I do not know exactly where the problem is.

My gradle file contains this:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
```

I try:

1. close/reopen AndroidStudio
2. reinstall java jdk
3. clean project / rebuild project
4. delete folder .gradle
5. rollback gradle file changes

but the problem continues.

Any Ideas? Thks.

**EDIT:** I've discovered that the problem is related to *Room Persistence Library* because when I comment this attribute:

```
@Database(entities = {Task.class}, version = 1)
```

The build runs successfully.

This is my Database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Task.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class MainDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static MainDatabase INSTANCE;

public abstract MainDao mainDao();

private static final Object sLock = new Object();

public static MainDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    MainDatabase.class, "tr.db")
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And this is my entity class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("TaskID")
    @Expose
    public int taskID;

    @SerializedName("TaskNumber")
    @Expose
    public int taskNumber;

    @Embedded
    @SerializedName("ParentTask")
    @Expose
    public Task parentTask;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly, I found the solution.

The build get stuck if there is a recursion in a Room entity.

The problem does not happen if I remove the recursion:

```
@Embedded
@SerializedName("ParentTask")
@Expose
public Task parentTask;
```

I was using the Room the wrong way. According to documentation (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#no-object-references):

> Room disallows object references between entity classes